# scikit-learn/GridSearchCV - The least populated class in y has only 2 members, which is less than n_splits=5

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to use `GridSearchCV` to perform hyperparameter tuning on a `RandomForrestClassifier`. For that, I have prepared a dataset (in `csv`), that looks like this: (with >8k rows):

```
| Consignor Code | Consignee Code | Origin | Destination | Carrier Code | 
|----------------|----------------|--------|-------------|--------------| 
| 23763          | 6404216422     | DKCPH  | CNPVG       | 6402746370   | 
| 87132          | 6404111479     | DKCPH  | USDEN       | 6402746424   | 
| 99553          | 65199597       | DKCPH  | MYKUL       | 6402746393   | 
| 99553          | 6407326944     | DKBLL  | AEDXB       | 6402746368   | 
| 99553          | 6407326944     | DKCPH  | AEDXB       | 6402746368   | 
...
```

Now in order to perform the hyperparameter tuning, I do this:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Import the dataset (A CSV file)
dataset = pd.read_csv('shipments_non_empty.csv',
                      header=0, skip_blank_lines=True)

# Drop the columns we don't need
dataset.drop(columns=['Consignor Code', 'Origin','Carrier Code'], inplace=True)

#Convert the 'Consignee Code' to a string.
dataset['Consignee Code'] = dataset['Consignee Code'].astype('int64')

#Set the target for the model
target = dataset.pop('Destination')

# Convert all our data to numeric values, so we can use the .fit function.
# For that, we use LabelEncoder

le_target = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target = le_target.fit_transform(list(target))

le_consignee = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dataset['Consignee Code'] = le_consignee.fit_transform(
    list(dataset['Consignee Code']))

# Prepare the dataset.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=None)


n_estimators = [100, 300, 500, 800, 1200]
max_depth = [5, 8, 15, 25, 30]
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10, 15, 100]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 5, 10]
param_grid = dict(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth,
                  min_samples_split=min_samples_split,
                  min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf)


rf = RandomForestClassifier()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=param_grid)
best_model = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(round(best_model.score(X_test, y_test), 2))
print(best_model.best_params_)
```

Now above code gives me the following error:

> The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=5

## What I have tried so far

After a lot of Googling and troubleshooting, I have found out that if any of my classes in my dataset have less than 5 records, then it is not enough for the model selection.

So I figured I could remove all the entries with less than 5 classes - right after importing the dataset:

```py
#Group column "Consignee Code" and remove if less than 5 records
dataset["CLASS_COUNT"] = dataset.groupby("Consignee Code").transform("count")
dataset.query('CLASS_COUNT > 5', inplace=True)
dataset.drop(columns=['CLASS_COUNT'], inplace=True)

#Group column "Destination" and remove if less than 5 records
dataset["CLASS_COUNT"] = dataset.groupby("Destination").transform("count")
dataset.query('CLASS_COUNT > 5', inplace=True)
dataset.drop(columns=['CLASS_COUNT'], inplace=True)
```

However, that still gives me the same error (just with a different number than before):

> The least populated class in y has only 3 members, which is less than n_splits=5

Comment: Some member of those classes may have gone to test set, leaving less than 5 records in training set

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan Is there any way I can filter on the train/test set and remove the records with less than 5?

Comment: I think with sklearn you'll have to do this before train/test split. Since you're reserving 33% for test set, I think removing classes with less than 9 members would be enough, since this would leave 2/3rd or 6 samples for training, enough for 5 splits